# Using [assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("System.Windows")] To expose Internal properties

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Ok so I had a qustion awhile back regarding [Silverlight 4 Data Binding with anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684954/silverlight-4-data-binding-with-anonymous-types), one of the answers was to use **[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("System.Windows")]** in your AssemblyInfo.cs file.

I tried this and it works!
I know I'm making all my internal properties classes and methods visible to the System.Windows Assembley.
But what kind of risk is this with the following in mind:

The product is a hosted silverlight based web application, so it wont be distributed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually it will be distributed to every client that accesses it, but that is not the point.

Information hiding is primarily a API design concern. If allowing a framework assembly to peek into your assemblies in order to facilitate your development I see no problems with it.

No one is going to be able to backdoor you if that is what you are worried about.

Comment: Yes, making sure I wasn't creating a huge security risk was what I was after. 
Thanks