# Silverlight linq-to-entities Anonymous type problem

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-entities, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to work with silverlight, wcf data services ( on the website code) and Linq-to-Entities. I know that anonymous types don't work on silverlight then I created a known class in order to retrieve some information. (I know the query it is not exactly intelligent, but It is only an example) but It is not working. can somebody help me???

this is the code.

```
public class DataSummary
{
    public DataSummary() { }

    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public string Account { get; set; }

    int accountID;
    string account;
}

  var p = (from q in svc.Accounts
                 select new DataSummary()
                 { AccountID = (int) q.AccountID,
                   Account = q.Account1
                 }) as DataServiceQuery<DataSummary>;

        p.BeginExecute(new AsyncCallback(r =>
        {
            try
            {
                this.grid.ItemsSource = p.EndExecute(r).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;
            }
        }), null);
```

when I run the example, the error message is

```
    ex.Message  "An error occurred while processing this request."  string
```

it is so funny, because it is not explaining the problem.

Also in this question

[Silverlight 4 Data Binding with anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684954/silverlight-4-data-binding-with-anonymous-types)

they said that we can used anonymous types, but then how can I put the "as DataServiceQuery.......... ??

Comment: Does `ex` have an `InnerException` that may shed more light on what actually went wrong? BTW I don't see any usage of an anonymous type here.

Comment: The real query includes 3 or 4 tables. so I wanted to do something easy

Comment: ase "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n<error xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\">\r\n  <code></code>\r\n  <message xml:lang=\"en-CA\">The response requires that version 2 of the protocol be used, but the MaxProtocolVersion of the data service is set to DataServiceProtocolVersion.V1.</message>\r\n</error>" System.InvalidOperationException {System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException}

Answer (score 0):

When Anthony told me about the inner exception. I discovered the error on the ProtocolVersion.

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);

    //On the service. You have to add this line
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
}
```

Thanks Anthony. I didn't know that the inner exception existed.