# Bind a Listbox from 2 tables

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am trying to bind a listbox from 2 tables. These 2 tables are related.

(windows phone project)

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox Name="LstOrders" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="12,11,12,12" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Height="643">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Margin="0">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding refe}"
                                           Tag="{Binding idOrder}"
                                           Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                           FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" 
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding tipo}"
                                           Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                           Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"
                                           FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding country}"
                                           Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                           Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"
                                           FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**C#**

EXAMPLE

```
using (ordersDBDataContext miDataContext = new ordersDBDataContext("Data Source='isostore:/mydatabase.sdf'"))
                {    
                    var _lista = from p in miDataContext.orders
                                     join t in miDataContext.tipos on p.idTipo equals t.idTipo 
                                     orderby p.refe
                                     where p.idCliente == _idCli
                                          select new 
                                          {
                                              p.refe, p.country,p.idOrder,t.tipo

                                          };

                    this.LstOrders.ItemsSource = _lista;                   
                }
```

**RESULT**

No display any data.What is wrong?

iF i doing this I can see that _lista contains correct data:

```
foreach (var rr in _lista)
{
       MessageBox.Show(rr.tipo);
}
```

Comment: What you can see in quick watch for _lista.ToList()? Is there any data there?

Comment: Hi Saeed: _lista contains the correct data. (now I have added more info in my question).

Comment: If you are right by `this.LstOrders.ItemsSource = _lista.ToList();` this should be solve.

Comment: same problem. But I have seeen that only runs if I execute the basic query (only 1 table): from p in miDataContext.orders orderby p.refe where p.idCliente == _idCli select p ......

Comment: Hi, I have similar problem with you. It do get the items, but when it tried to enter the page, it give me error and out of the application. I tried add assembly and all your solution, is there anything you missed to show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are disposing your DataContext (correctly), but this means when the _lista query is executed the DataContext will no longer be valid and there will be an exception.  WPF unhelpfully swallows exceptions in certain circumstances so you probably aren't seeing the exception.

The solution is to use:

```
this.LstOrders.ItemsSource = _lista.ToList();
```

and also to either remove `ItemsSource={Binding}` from your xaml or alternatively leave the binding in and use

```
this.LstOrders.DataContext = _lista.ToList();
```

Also, see [Silverlight 4 Data Binding with anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684954/silverlight-4-data-binding-with-anonymous-types) which may be relevant to your problem.

Comment: Hi Phil: I have tried this but display no data. But I have seen that _lista contains data but is not binded

Comment: Can we see the items control that's using the DataTemplate?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.  You can try removing the ItemsSource={Binding} since you're explicitly setting ItemsSource.  Also try removing the TiltEffect in case there's something strange going on. I would have used ItemsSource={Binding} if I had set LstOrders.DataContext= _lista.ToList();

Comment: same result. no data. But now I have seen that if I do this basic query, then listbox display data:     from p in miDataContext.orders
  orderby p.refe  where p.idCliente == _idCli  select p

Comment: perhaps WP7 can't handle binding to anonymous types.  Try specifying the type, as in  'select new Order{ refe=p.refe, ... };'

Comment: Thanks Phil. Now runs fine. Solution is in the link that you have posted :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of your code snippet but I'm guessing you probably need to call

```
this.LstOrders.Items.Refresh();
```

I cant exactly explain why cos I am not familiar with WPF, but in winforms it would have been a DataBind().