# Binding with an anonymous object on WP7.5

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

On WP7.5 I created a datacontext like this:

```
this.DataContext = new { One = listOne, Two = listTwo};
```

On my XAML code I tried this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding listOne.m_strTypeTiers}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding listTwo.m_strTypeTiers}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
```

My textbox are empty. I think my binding syntax has a mistake.

Comment: What does `this` refer to? You may also want to check your output for WPF binding warning messages.

Comment: My xamlFile is named page1.xaml, and this is on my cs page, named page1.xaml.cs. This the Page1.xaml.cs instance.

Comment: And an important thing, if i make " this.datacontext = ListOne " the binding is ok. My problem comes from the {one = ListOne, two = ListTwo}.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `{Binding One.m_strTypeTiers}`

But it depends on what listOne and listTwo are. Are they classes with a property named m_strTypeTiers? If m_strTypeTiers is a field, then you will not be able to databind to it. Databinding only works with properties ([by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/843051/211627)).

---

**UPDATE**
Oops. [Silverlight does not support binding to anonymous types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569040/silverlight-and-binding-to-anonymous-types). I was thinking of WPF for desktop applications. [Windows Phone 7 uses Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9390151/211627) which is very similar but different in some important ways. I think you are out of luck - you will need to define a concrete class.

You may find this article helpful in the future:
[Contrasting Silverlight and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) (...not that it would have helped you with this particular question)

Comment: It's a class, and They are properties :)

Comment: In that case, you may want to consider reading up on Microsoft's [Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for this link, nevertheless, i tried {Binding One.m_strTypeTiers} with no succes :(